# MVC 5 Html.TextBoxFor autofocus not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't seem to get this to work. I've found multiple examples of just applying an autofocus or just a CSS class but I haven't been able to get this combination to work. With the following code I get the "form-control" CSS and he placeholder to work but the "autofocus" is not. I've tried multiple combinations from Html.TextBox to Html.EditFor to Html.TextBoxFor and I just can't seem to get the autofocus to work.

Anyone know what I'm missing to get this to work?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CostCenter,
    new
    {
        Class = "form-control", 
        placeholder = "Enter Cost Center",
        autofocus = ""
    })
```

Comment: This syntax works for me locally and via [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hgaQaI).  Can you produce a [verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  where this happens?

Comment: @stephen.vakil, thanks for pointing out dotnetfiddle.

Comment: Looks like it's working in dotnetfiddle so not sure what's going on with my code. Guess I'm going to dig some more.

Comment: .net version plz?

Comment: I'm using .Net v4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me

```html
@Html.TexBoxFor(c=>c.CostCenter, new{@class="form-control",@placeholder = "Enter Cost Center",@autofocus=""})
```